# Scala implicit conversion: converting Int to List does not print list on printing the integer variable

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am experimenting with implicit conversion feature of scala.

I tried writing a method for implicit conversion from Int to List of three same integers

Although the list methods are applicable, but when we print the value it still shows as Integer

```
scala> implicit def conversion(x:Int) = List(x,x,x)
conversion: (x: Int)List[Int]

scala> 1
res31: Int = 1

scala> res31.length
res32: Int = 3

scala> res31.tail
res33: List[Int] = List(1, 1)

scala> println(res31)
1
```

Any ideas why it is showing such behavior? Ideally it should print like following:

```
List(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversions do only kick in when the original value cannot be applied, e.g. there is no method with such parameter. Because you can print an Int there is "no need" for scala to apply a conversion. You can force it with: 
`println(res31:List[Int])`

Answer (score 1):

See the document: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions.html

> Implicit conversions are applied in two situations:
>
> If an expression e is of type S, and S does not conform to the expression’s expected type T.
> In a selection e.m with e of type S, if the selector m does not denote a member of S.

so for your example, there is no `type conversion` occur except `res31.tail`, In `res31.tail` need to call `List` type `tail` method, this action trigger `implicit` conversion. the other actions not trigger **implicit conversion**.

Answer (score 1):

`println` expects an argument of type `Any`, so there is no need for implicit conversion. In the first two cases, `Int` does not have methods named `length` or `tail` but `List` has them, that's why conversion takes place in those expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To print as a list you can use,
println(res53.toList)